# Need Vaadin navigation control with two arrows on left and right like on passed link

Tags: vaadin, vaadin7

I am extremely new to Vaadin, and I don't know all controls, I tried to google but didn't find type of control. My question is which is control visible on this link

http://demo.vaadin.com/sampler/#foundation/cssinject

which is used for navigation (left and right arrow buttons on left and right side of screen which you press to change content in middle or something like this doesn't exist in vaadin by default and this is in jquery ?) ?
I need to implement this, to change content on click, to allow user to iterate through shopping cart like this.

Answer (score 0):

They are probably just buttons.  Imagine 3 columns Button | Content | Button

Button.onclick -> Load Content

Comment: I am asking about transition animation, it is easy to do in jquery and in android already exists but I wonder is in Vaadin some default transition for this or already coded control with this. Thanks

Comment: If you can do it in css then create a style and attach it to your component with `setStyleName(java.lang.String style)`

Answer (score 0):

I use this [carousel](https://vaadin.com/directory#addon/carousel%3avaadin) add-on which does that. Buttons are bigger but can be changed using css.
It has a nice transition effect, sliding left and right.